# How to efficiently share dicts and lists between processes using ProcessPool

Tags: python-3.x, pathos

Let's consider the following example:

```
from pathos.pools import ProcessPool

class A:
    def run(self, arg: int):

        my_list = list(...)
        my_dict = dict(...)

        def __run_parallel(arg: int):
            local_variable = 42

            # some code and read access...

            read_only1 = my_list[...]
            read_only2 = dict[...]


            # some code and write access...

            my_list.append(arg)
            my_dict[arg] = local_variable

        ProcessPool(4).map(__run_parallel, range(1000))
```

Since it seems as if `list` nor `dict` is thread-safe, I'm searching for a way to *efficiently* share access to these variables to all processes in the pool.

So far, I've tried to pass `my_list` and `my_dict` as additional arguments to `__run_parallel` using `pa.helpers.mp.Manager`. However, even though it works, it's horrendously slow (as it's obviously built for distributed systems).

Since I'm working on this in a trial and error session now for multiple evenings, I'd like to ask whether somebody knows how to *efficiently* use a shared `dict` and `list` within `__run_parallel` using `pathos`.

Comment: Could you use an `pathos.helpers.mp.Array` or work with the `numpy` `ctypes` interface more directly?  You'd have to work with shared memory arrays, not lists and dicts.  Arrays are intended for shared memory use, lists and dicts are not.  The efficiency also depends on what you have in the list/dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting both `list` and `dict` variables to `pathos.helpers.mp.Array` without an intermediate `pa.helpers.mp.Manager` as suggested by @Mike McKerns brought the desired performance boost.